# Group OHLC-Stockmarket Data into multiple timeframes with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, timestamp, finance

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and need to create new tables grouped in Time intervals.

The data is data from a stock market index. I have the data in 1 minute intervals, now i need them in 5,10,15,30,45,60...minute intervals. My primary key is the time stamp.

My question is: how to query the 1 minute data table to return data that is grouped by a specific time interval for example 5 minute intervals.

The query must return the Highest, Lowest, Last and First values in that particular group and most importantly also the last entry of the time-stamp in the group.

I'm very new to the SQL language and have tried numerous code found on the net, but i cant get to exactly return the desired results.

**Data:**

```
TimeStamp          | Open | High | Low | Close
2012-02-17 15:15:0 | 102  | 110  |100  |105
2012-02-17 15:16:0 |106   |112   |105  |107
2012-02-17 15:17:0 | 106  |110   |98   |105
2012-02-17 15:18:0 |105   |109   |104  |106
2012-02-17 15:19:0 |107   |112   |107  |112
2012-02-17 15:20:0 |115   |125   |115  |124
```

**Desired Query Result (5 minutes):**

```
Timestamp       |Open|High|Low|Close
2012-02-15:19:0 |102 |125 |98 |124
2012-02-15:24:0 |115.|....|...|...
2012-02-15:29:0 |....|....|...|...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you convert a `datetime` to a `float`, you get a number of days.  If you multiply that by `24 * 12`, you get a number of 5 minute intervals.  So if you group on:

```
cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
```

you can do aggregates per five minutes:

```
select  min(timestamp)
,       max(high) as Highest
,       min(low) as Lowest
from    @t
group by
        cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
```

Finding the first and the last row is tricky in SQL Server.  Here's one way using `row_number`:

```
select  min(timestamp)
,       max(high) as Highest
,       min(low) as Lowest
,       min(case when rn_asc = 1 then [open] end) as first
,       min(case when rn_desc = 1 then [close] end) as Last
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
                    order by timestamp) as rn_asc
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
                    order by timestamp desc) as rn_desc
        ,       *
        from    @t
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
```

Here's a [working example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61772/new)