# MySql timestamp rounding then reformatting in human readable format

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following query from [Group OHLC-Stockmarket Data into multiple timeframes - Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520257/group-ohlc-stockmarket-data-into-multiple-timeframes-mysql).

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(MIN(`timestamp`)/"+period+")*"+period+" AS timestamp,
  SUM(amount) AS volume,
  SUM(price*amount)/sum(amount) AS wavg_price,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(MIN(CONCAT(`timestamp`, '_', price)), '_', -1) AS `open`,
  MAX(price) AS high,
  MIN(price) AS low,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(`timestamp`, '_', price)), '_', -1) AS `close`
FROM transactions_history -- this table has 3 columns (timestamp, amount, price)
GROUP BY FLOOR(`timestamp`/"+period+")
ORDER BY timestamp
```

In my select statement, `FLOOR(MIN(timestamp)/"+period+")*"+period+" AS timestamp,`

1. I am trying to understand what it is doing. and
2. I need to convert this back to a mysql date/time `Y-M-D H:i:s` string or a UTC timestamp for parsing via javascript.

Let's assume that `+period+` is 86400 (The number of seconds in a day)
Let's assume that the timestamp is '2015-12-08 20:58:58'
From what I can see, it takes the timestamp, which internally is stored as an integer and divides by 86400.

`'2015-12-08 20:58:58' / 86400 = 233231576.4566898000`

It then uses the FLOOR operation which would make it `233231576` then multiplies by 86400 again (I assume that this is to ensure rounding to the day)

I end up with `20151208166400`.

So that's the 8th December 2015 but I also have 166400 which I have no idea what it is?

So now the second part of the question is, how to convert this integer to `2015-12-08 %H:%i:%s` or even a UTC timestamp for parsing via Javascript.

Comment: I am guessing that the timestamp from the code is a unix timestamp, not a datetime column.

Comment: Of Course! I've been really dumb here. If you want to place `FLOOR(MIN(unix_timestamp(`timestamp`))/"+period+")*"+period+" AS timestamp,` ill mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned the problem in the comment, but not a fix.  The problem is that the proposed code is for a unix timestamp, not a datetime value.

This can be fixed by doing appropriate conversions

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(timestamp)) / $period) * $period)
```

This gives you the flexibility of have arbitrary numbers of seconds for the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a `Date` object to a `string`, according to universal time:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

The result of `n` will be:

> Mon, 28 Dec 2015 12:57:32 GMT

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `FLOOR(timestamp / 86400) * 86400` is a crude way of rounding a UNIX-style timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00UTC) to midnight on the present day UTC.

If that's what you're trying to do, I suggest you try this kind of MySQL code:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d'),
        ...
  GROUP BY DATE(`timestamp`)
```

This uses MySQL's built in date arithmetic to turn a timestamp into midnight.

But you should be careful of one thing. Those timestamps are all stored in UTC (f/k/a Greenwich Mean Time). When you do date arithmetic with them, or pull them out of the database to use them, they're automatically converted to local time according to your MySQL time zone settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is rounding timestampt to period (e.g day).
2. DATE_FORMAT( DATE( FLOOR(MIN(`timestamp`)/"+period+")*"+period+" ) , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )

If period==day consider using only MySQL period rounding by DAY().