# Spark SQL can use FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE in a GROUP BY aggregation (but it's not standard)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

(Tested on Spark 2.2 and 2.3)

I am using Spark to aggregate stock trading ticks into daily OHLC (open-high-low-close) records.

The input data is like

```
val data = Seq(("2018-07-11 09:01:00", 34.0), ("2018-07-11 09:04:00", 32.0), ("2018-07-11 09:02:00", 35.0), ("2018-07-11 09:03:00", 30.0), ("2018-07-11 09:00:00", 33.0), ("2018-07-12 09:01:00", 56.0), ("2018-07-12 09:04:00", 54.0), ("2018-07-12 09:02:00", 51.0), ("2018-07-12 09:03:00", 50.0), ("2018-07-12 09:00:00", 51.0)).toDF("time", "price")

data.createOrReplaceTempView("ticks")

data.show

scala>
```

shown as

```
+-------------------+-----+
|               time|price|
+-------------------+-----+
|2018-07-11 09:01:00| 34.0|
|2018-07-11 09:04:00| 32.0|
|2018-07-11 09:02:00| 35.0|
|2018-07-11 09:03:00| 30.0|
|2018-07-11 09:00:00| 33.0|
|2018-07-12 09:01:00| 56.0|
|2018-07-12 09:04:00| 54.0|
|2018-07-12 09:02:00| 51.0|
|2018-07-12 09:03:00| 50.0|
|2018-07-12 09:00:00| 51.0|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Desired output is

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|      date|open|high| low|close|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|2018-07-11|33.0|35.0|30.0| 32.0|
|2018-07-12|51.0|56.0|50.0| 54.0|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
```

There have been many SQL solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520257/group-ohlc-stockmarket-data-into-multiple-timeframes-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840829/using-group-by-with-first-value-and-last-value).

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(time) AS date,
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_DATE(time) ORDER BY time) AS open,
    MAX(price) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_DATE(time) ORDER BY time) AS high,
    MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_DATE(time) ORDER BY time) AS low,
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_DATE(time) ORDER BY time) AS close
FROM ticks
```

Due to the limitation of SQL, these solutions are cumbersome.

Today, I found Spark SQL can use `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` in a `GROUP BY` context, [which is not allowed in standard SQL](http://julianhyde.blogspot.com/2008/09/sql-extension-to-allow-firstvalue-and.html).

This unlimitation of Spark SQL derives a neat and tidy solution like this:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(time) AS date,
    FIRST_VALUE(price) AS open,
    MAX(price) AS high,
    MIN(price) AS low,
    LAST_VALUE(price) AS close
FROM ticks
GROUP BY TO_DATE(time)
```

You can try it

```
spark.sql("SELECT TO_DATE(time) AS date, FIRST(price) AS open, MAX(price) AS high, MIN(price) AS low, LAST(price) AS close FROM ticks GROUP BY TO_DATE(time)").show

scala>
```

shown as

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|      date|open|high| low|close|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|2018-07-11|34.0|35.0|30.0| 33.0|
|2018-07-12|56.0|56.0|50.0| 51.0|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
```

However, the above result is incorrect. (Please compare with the above desired result.)

`FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` need a deterministic ordering to get deterministic results.

I can correct it by adding an `orderBy` before grouping.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

data.orderBy("time").groupBy(expr("TO_DATE(time)").as("date")).agg(first("price").as("open"), max("price").as("high"), min("price").as("low"), last("price").as("close")).show

scala>
```

shown as

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|      date|open|high| low|close|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|2018-07-11|33.0|35.0|30.0| 32.0|
|2018-07-12|51.0|56.0|50.0| 54.0|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
```

which is correct as desired !!!

My question is, is the above code 'orderBy then groupBy' valid?  Is this ordering guaranteed?  Can we use this non-standard feature in serious productions?

The point of this question is that, in standard SQL, we can only do a `GROUP BY` then `ORDER BY` to sort the aggregation, but not `ORDER BY` then `GROUP BY`.
The `GROUP BY` will ignore the ordering of `ORDER BY`.

I also wonder if Spark SQL can do such a `GROUP BY` under desired ordering, can standard SQL also invent such a syntax for this?

P.S.

I can think of some aggregation functions that depend on deterministic ordering.

```
WITH ORDER BY time SELECT COLLECT_LIST(price) GROUP BY stockID

WITH ORDER BY time SELECT SUM(SQUARE(price - LAG(price, 1, 0))) GROUP BY stockID
```

Without the `WITH ORDER BY time`, how can we sort the COLLECTed_LIST in standard SQL?

These examples show that "`GROUP BY` under desired ordering" is still useful.

Comment: I wonder what's the point of providing `first_value, last_value` if we can use it like this, what's the intended use case if not this? :(

Comment: If some query result is ordered, and its grouping is order-preserving, then we can have first_value, last_value, min, max, sum, count ... in one pass.  Don't need multiple partition-by statements.  I believe spark's orderby+groupby is order-preserving because I got the correct result in the above example.

Comment: As for use cases, I have shown 2: `COLLECT_LIST` and `price - LAG(price)` in the P.S. section of my question.  The real intended use case was REALLY computing OHLC for stock ticks.

Answer (score 4):

Ordering in groupBy/agg not guaranted, you can use window function with partition by key and ordering by time

Comment: I have not chosen your answer because I can't tell whether what you said "not guaranteed" is true or not.  Maybe it is guaranteed but not documented?  If you provide more evidence such as documentation or source code study, I will choose your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: What you provide about window functions was one of the known solutions in the hyperlinks in my question.  My question is based on this.  To make it clarified, I just now edited my question to add the windowing SQL statement.