# tick by tick to candlestick/OHLC data in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, group-by, finance

My question is based on this premise:
[Group OHLC-Stockmarket Data into multiple timeframes with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340602/group-ohlc-stockmarket-data-into-multiple-timeframes-with-t-sql)

Like the asker of that question, I aim to construct candlestick data from a SQL source, but entirely in C#. In other words, I want to download the tick by tick data in its entirety to my C# program first, and then manipulate it in the program to get results as follows:

```
TimeStamp          | Price 
2012-02-17 15:15:0 | 102  
2012-02-17 15:16:0 |108   
2012-02-17 15:17:0 | 101  
2012-02-17 15:18:0 |105   
2012-02-17 15:19:0 |107   
2012-02-17 15:20:0 |115   

Desired Query Result (5 minutes):

Timestamp       |Open|High|Low|Close
2012-02-15:19:0 |102 |108 |101|107
2012-02-15:24:0 |115.|....|...|...
2012-02-15:29:0 |....|....|...|...
```

(reprinted partially from question above)

My code in C# downloads the entire tick by tick data using the relevant connection strings, and stores the data in arrays.

```
//SQL connection string
SqlConnection o_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
o_sqlCommand.CommandText = "(see query below)";
SqlDataReader o_sqlDataReader;
...
//Storage of query result in arrays
pricetmp = Convert.ToDouble(o_sqlDataReader["Price"]);
            priceList.Add(pricetmp);
voltmp = Convert.ToDouble(o_sqlDataReader["Volume"]);
            volList.Add(voltmp);
//along with date, time and stock symbol
//eventually
double[] priceArray = price.ToArray();
DateTime[] timestampArray = timestamp.ToArray();
...
```

I need help with writing the part of the code that yields the same results as the SQL query in the answer to the question above, i.e.

```
(reprinted from the link)
select  min(timestamp) as Time
,       max(Price) as Highest
,       min(Price) as Lowest
,       min(case when rn_asc = 1 then [Price] end) as first
,       min(case when rn_desc = 1 then [Price] end) as Last
from    (
    select  row_number() over (
                partition by cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
                order by timestamp) as rn_asc
    ,       row_number() over (
                partition by cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
                order by timestamp desc) as rn_desc
    ,       where Stocksymbol = 'abc123'
    ,       *
    from    @t
    ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
    cast(cast(timestamp as float) * 24 * 12 as int)
```

Note: I've modified the query above to suit my purpose - i.e. convert tick data (rather than shorter timeframe OHLC data) to OHLC data directly.

As a newbie to C#, I would appreciate some advice on how to code a function that mimics the result of the query above.
Here is what I have so far:

```
int j = 0; //n is length of data per expected number of OHLC bars
double[] open = new double[n];
double[] close = new double[n];
double[] high = new double[n];
double[] low = new double[n];
int i = 0; int ratio = priceData.Length/n;
while (i < priceData.Length)
{
    open[i/ratio] = priceData[i];
    close[i/ratio] = priceData[i];
    high[i/ratio] = priceData[i];
    low[i/ratio] = priceData[i];

    if (i != -1)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < i + ratio; j++)
        {
        if (priceData[j] > high[i/ratio])
            high[i/ratio] = priceData[j];
        if (priceData[j] < low[i/ratio])
            low[i/ratio] = priceData[j];
        close[i/ratio] = priceData[j];
        }
    }

    i += ratio;
}
//output open, high, low, close
```

How do I select parameters for the n values based on expected timeframes? (1 min, 2 mins, 15 mins etc.) (as is easy to do in the SQL data)? Or more specifically, how do I generalize  this code to input the required timeframe and use it to calculate the OHLC data? And how do I incorporate the use of the DateTime array (which this example code ignores) to sort the data?

This seems easier to do in SQL because the 24 x 12 calculations, which yields 5 minute data, can be modified to other numbers (eg 24 x 4 for 15 minute data, 24 x 30 for 2 minute data, etc.) for different timeframes. But I need to do this entirely in C#.

My tick-by-tick times are generally every 3 milliseconds, but there is no fixed or consistent number of ticks in the data.

Answer (score -1):

why you dont use DataManipulator.Group method of chart series ?

you can do like this :

```
    chart.DataManipulator.Group("HiLoOpCl", 5, IntervalType.Minutes, "series1", "series2")
```

I think its better .