# How do I aggregate open and close values in QuestDB using SAMPLE BY

Tags: aggregate-functions, questdb, ohlc

I'm working on a price data project, trying to store OHLC 1 minute data and then sampling it over various intervals. I decided to try QuestDB for its neat time-series features such as `SAMPLE BY` but am running into a wall.

I want to use `SAMPLE BY` to query my data, which looks like this:

| timestamp | open | high | low | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2021-09-10T19:43:21.657672Z" | 2.0 | 4.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| "2021-09-15T06:12:42.267416Z" | 3.0 | 6.0 | 3.0 | 6.0 |

For example, for the two rows above, which are in the same month, I would like to run `SAMPLE BY 1M` and aggregate the values for the month.

For high and low values the aggregate functions are `min(low)` and `max(high)`, but I can't figure out what to do for open and close values.

I tried retrofitting [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340602/group-ohlc-stockmarket-data-into-multiple-timeframes-with-t-sql) but got as far as the following without errors:

```sql
with ohlc as ( 
    select row_number() over (
        partition by cast(cast(timestamp as float) / 1000000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7 / 4.34524 as int)
        order by timestamp
    ), open, high, low, close, timestamp
    from eurusd
) 
select max(high) high,
    min(low) low,
    min(case when rn_asc = 1 then [open] end) as open
from ohlc
```

Some errors I encountered:

1. Adding the second `row_number() over [...] order by timestamp desc` fails with a syntax error. If I remove the `desc` it works, so I just removed that column altogether since then it's the same as the first.
2. Neither `SAMPLE BY` nor `GROUP BY` at the end works with "base query does not provide dedicated TIMESTAMP column" and "group by expression does not match anything select in statement" errors, respectively.
3. QuestDB recognizes the `CASE WHEN THEN` but if I yield a column name in the `THEN` portion it doesn't work with no error message.

I'm currently stuck at this point having looked across the QuestDB tutorials, SO questions, and GitHub issues for a mention of this because it seems like a common operation, especially since they have written many price time-series data tutorials, but none address this.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this and has a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be `first()` and `last()` to get open and close.

```
select max(high) high,
    min(low) low,
    first(open) as open,
    last(close) as close
from ohlc
SAMPLE BY 1M
```

Comment: Goodness, I overthought that. Thank you so much!